# Cloning a LinkList without using any builtin functions.

Tags: java

I went to interview today and this question got thrown at me. I can't come up with an answer.

the gig is 
SList2 = SList1.clone();

if you change things in SList1 (e.g editing the object) it will not affect the similar object in SList2. I attempt it, I create new nodes but whenever I get to the cloning object part I failed. Was thinking about object.clone() but the question state that no built-in function is allowed.

Comment: a LinkList is a LinkedList? It will give you a shallow copy .. if you add a new element to the list it won't be affected to the another list, but if you modifiy an existing element in original list it will reflected in clone list.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a copy of a list?  As in, how to make a new list that contains all the same values in the same order as a given list?  Hint:  That's a two part problem.  (1) How do you visit all of the members of the given list, and (2) how do you make a list and add values to it in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

```
Slist2.head = new Node();
Node newList = Slist2.head; 
Node head = Slist1.head;
Slist.head.(all data) = head.(all data);
while(head.hasNext()){
    head = head.next();
    Node newGuy = newNode();
    newNode.(all data) = node.(all data)
    newList.next = newGuy;
}
```

This will follow through the old list, manually copying all data into a new node and tacking that node on to the new list

Answer (score 0):

This is two problems disguised as one.

- How would I read in the *values* from the linked list object, and
- How would I create it in such a way that no references were reused (that is, I don't just reassign the head of one list to the head of the other)?

Without diving into code, let's look at this at a high level.  Provided that your linked list can provide iteration (that is, it has an `Iterator`-like object that keeps its state in the list, and returns a node when `next()` is referenced), then the first problem becomes a matter of iterating over the linked list via the iterator.

From there, you would want to peel out the raw value from what you're iterating over, and *add* them into your new linked list object.

You're pretty much done then; nothing fancy needs to be worked out.  It's literally taking data from one structure and inserting it into another.